# MediaSession Extra to reserve the Android Auto playback queue slot does not work? (ALWAYS_RESERVE_SPACE_FOR.ACTION_QUEUE)

Tags: android, android-auto, android-mediasession

Multiple documentation sources and sample apps explain how to provide specific Extra values to the `MediaSession.setExtras(Bundle)` in order to reserve the spaces used for standard Android Auto media action buttons even when those actions are not currently available. This is intended to prevent custom actions from reflowing into vacant slots on the primary action card from the secondary action card. For example, the [Setting Standard Playback Actions section of Providing Audio Playback for Auto](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/audio/#required-actions) documentation states:

> Android Auto reserves space in its UI for the playback queue and the
>   ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS or ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS actions. If your
>   app does not support any of these functions the UI will not display
>   controls for them. It will assign the unused space to any custom
>   actions you create. **If you do not want to fill those spaces with
>   custom actions, you can "reserve" them so that Android Auto will
>   display the coresponding button when an action is enabled, and leave
>   the space blank when the action is not enabled or the play queue does
>   not exist**.
>
> To reserve space, call setExtras() with a bundle that contains the
>   keys defined below. Set each key to the boolean value true:
>
> // Use these extras to show the transport control buttons for the
>   corresponding actions, even when they are not enabled in the
>   PlaybackState.
>
> private static final String SLOT_RESERVATION_SKIP_TO_NEXT =
>       "com.google.android.gms.car.media.ALWAYS_RESERVE_SPACE_FOR.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT";
>
> private static final String SLOT_RESERVATION_SKIP_TO_PREV =
>       "com.google.android.gms.car.media.ALWAYS_RESERVE_SPACE_FOR.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS";
>
> private static final String SLOT_RESERVATION_QUEUE =
>       "com.google.android.gms.car.media.ALWAYS_RESERVE_SPACE_FOR.ACTION_QUEUE";

However, in my experience, only two of the three Extras function correctly. The Extras to reserve the Next and Previous slots work as documented, but I have never been able to get the Queue reservation Extra to work.  If the MediaSession queue is null or empty, Android Auto always hides the Queue button and reflows a custom action button into the first slot, ignoring the slot reservation Extra if it is provided.

The issue is easy to reproduce with a few small changes to [Google's Universal Media Player sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer); simply set a null or empty Queue, define several custom actions, and you will see the Queue reservation flag is ignored. The UMP sample project includes a [CarHelper class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/utils/CarHelper.java) that assists with setting the appropriate Extras. You can find variations of it in most Android Auto media app examples.

Is there a known issue with the Queue reservation Extra? Has anyone seen the Queue reservation Extra work?